# why is is my service working returning a bad response code and ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, terminal, localhost, service-worker

I've been working on an app for a class project and everything has been fine until I need to make a service worker. In Bash I create a local server with python using `py -m http.server`(I've tried other ways but this is the only thats worked). Following a tutorial I use the code:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
  navigator.serviceWorker
  .register('/sw.js')
  .catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

I've referenced https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register but still get errors.  I assume it has something to do with the way the local server is set up. I'm very new to 'server side' things and just don't know enough about it to troubleshoot.  Here are my errors.

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
main.js:219 TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
(anonymous) @ main.js:219
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ main.js:218
```

js: 219 and js: 218 are

```
 .catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
```

from the snippet above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks like it can't find the file.

Comment: Thanks! that what I'm starting to suspect.  The file is there, and I've cleared my cache many many many times.  Do you have any advice you can offer?